# Position simplemodal modal on top of an existing div

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm trying to position a modal dialog on top of an existing div, using simplemodal plugin.

Here's my code; it's not working:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('.slider-caption .basic').click(function (e) {

        var p = $("#slider1");
        var position = p.position();

        $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
            position: "absolute",
            left: position.left,
            top: position.top
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

It's still drawing in the middle of the window. I've also tried to set `autoPosition` option to false, but that just makes it draw below the existing content at the left.

I'm using version 1.4.1 of simplemodal.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did to get it to work:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.slider-caption .basic').click(function (e) {

        var position = $("#slider1").offset();

        $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
            appendTo: "#slider1",
            autoPosition: false,
            position: "absolute",
            left: position.left,
            top: position.top
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's extraneous stuff in there. it's just the appendTo which does it, really nice:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.slider-caption .basic').click(function (e) {

        $('#basic-modal-content').modal({appendTo:"#slider1", autoPosition: false,});

        return false;
    });
});
```