# absolutely position simplemodal plugin on top of an existing div

Tags: simplemodal

I posted this a week or so ago:
[Position simplemodal modal on top of an existing div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160138/position-simplemodal-modal-on-top-of-an-existing-div)
and thought that I had solved my problem, but when the window is scrolled, the modal container moves.
I think I need to change it from fixed to absolute positioning, but when I change it in the script, the right side of the container lines up with the left side of the div (but it does stay in the same place vertically).

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
  $('.slider-caption #large-spot-two').click(function (e) {

    $('#basic-modal-content-two').modal({appendTo:"#slider1", autoPosition: false});

    return false;
});
```

What's the best way for me to keep the modal container above the div, whether the page is scrolled or not?
Thanks,
Wendy

Answer (score 0):

The plugin was created to be fixed (not move when the page is scrolled, etc.). Changing the CSS position works until the page is resized or scrolled, as you have found.

The code required to change that behavior would require more work that I currently have time for. You might try BlockUI, as it sounds like that would fit your needs better?